# How to create datetime from date and time in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project with AngularJs. 
Here I have 3 html controls.

- datepicker (html5's **date**) => `$scope.date`
- timepicker (html5's **time**) => `$scope.from`
- timepicker (html5's **time**) => `$scope.to`

below is html code.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Set date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <!-- <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email"> -->
      <datepicker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" selector="form-control">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a date" ng-model="date" id="date" />
          <spam class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="fa fa-lg fa-calendar"></i>
          </spam>
        </div>
      </datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Set time</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="From" ng-model="from" id="from">
    </div>
    <label for="" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">To</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="To" ng-model="to" id="to">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

now for service call i need to pass datetime, but here I'm having **date** and **time** separately.

How can I construct datetime from and datetime to from above available data?

Comment: You need to share the HTML and JS, or a working snippet with the problem for debugging the issue!

Comment: @NarenMurali I have provided HTML. well right now there's no useful JS hence I haven't included it. **Problem is how to construct complete date time from from date and time? for example. datetimeFrom and datetimeTo from data selected by a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the dates in a function in your controller. First format the dates/times using the [**Date.prototype.toISOString()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method, then use the [**String.prototype.substring()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method to take the `datePart` and the `timePart` separately, finally combine the two to create a new `Date` instance.

```
$scope.fromDate = getCombinedDateTime($scope.date, $scope.from);
$scope.toDate = getCombinedDateTime($scope.date, $scope.to);

function getCombinedDateTime(date, time){
  var datePart = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  var timePart = time.toISOString().substring(10, 24);
  return new Date(datePart + timePart);
}
```